# Mac interface for logging in on first session is different from the usual one

Tags: catalina, startup, ui, authentication

When I am signing in to my user account, there is a user interface with a black or white (about the dark mode or light mode is selected) background, there are two text boxes for username and password. When you type the username and press enter if the user is found you hear two beep sounds and get to the password part; if the user is not found you hear one beep sound and you type your username again. In the password part, you get a beep sound for every character you enter, if your password is correct you get three beep sounds.

**How can I fix this, I want the normal (*select user, enter password*) user interface?**

My environment is:
MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012), MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! The first thing you may want to try is [resetting the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

Comment: Resetting the NVRAM or SMC usually isn't the best thing to try *first*. Can you add a photo of the screen? Also, do you have FileVault enabled?

Comment: What do you mean by adding a photo to the screen, a background image? And wow, I did not know my FileVault was enabled, is this because of FileVault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common complaint when people first experience a reboot on a Mac protected with file vault. The log in screen for the OS is similar to the Pre-boot screen on first glance, but they work very differently under the hood.

When you set up your Mac, the user icons and settings that the OS has set, get saved outside the “encrypted” portion of the disk so that when the machine starts up from a powered down state, the OS is not decrypted yet and you see the pre-boot screen.

Once you authenticate, the disk is unlocked and the OS starts, only then would you see the fully functioning Lock Screen or log in screen. They behave differently since one has the full macOS running and the other does not.

Answer (score 0):

When FileVault (System Preferences/ Security & Privacy/ FileVault) is open to activate the mac you need to enter an administrator password or the recovery key (or Apple ID for reset). The password screen appears when you want to open either a non administrator, guest, or administrator user.

**The username-password UI appears when opening the mac, to get rid of it turn off FileVault from System Preferences/ Security & Privacy/ FileVault.**

> *FileVault secures the data on your disk by encrypting its content*
> *automatically.*